# How to handle SwipeRefreshLayout on refresh?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, swiperefreshlayout

I want to reload a page with Kotlin when the swipe refresh button is pulled down. I cant find any tutorials on this for Kotlin. This gives me a datatype mismatch, how to do it right?

```
swipe_container.setOnRefreshListener { view ->
    webview1.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`OnRefreshListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/swiperefreshlayout/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener.html) doesn't pass a `view` parameter - your code should be

```
swipe_container.setOnRefreshListener {
    webview1.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Datatype mismatch could be because you're trying to pass `view` inside `setOnrefreshListener`.

```
swipe_container.setOnRefreshListener {
    webview1.loadUrl("https://google.com/")
}
```

This should work for you, i'd also suggest to checkout this [page](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/02/android-kotlin-swiperefreshlayout.html) for an example on implementing swipe refresh functionality on your page.